# Setting Audio Alerts or Alarms in Linux Mint to alert the user. SOFTWARE IN THE OS

Tags: linux-mint

I've recently installed Linux Mint 17.1 MATE (64Bit) on my Dell E6410 because I( had encountered so many viruses on WIN 7 Pro (64Bit).   However I find my- self missing a few things I took for granted!!!
How can I set up in Linux (LM) the sounding of audio as in Windows the Alert for when someone plugs or unplugs (connects or disconnects) a USB device or cable.   Also if something is not "fully connected" an "unabled or disabled" audio alert is sounded!

Comment: 17.1 is many versions old at this point.  Consider downloading the current version (18.2), which will have a lot of updates, improvements, bug fixes, and drivers for recent hardware.  Most of those settings are in the System Settings interface.  Unfortunately, each desktop environment organizes the options a little differently, and Mint varies the implementation from version to version.  The easiest way to find them may be to use the search bar in System Settings.  Try keywords like sounds, notifications, or alerts.  (cont'd)

Comment: You're describing mostly system sounds.  You can often also create your own alert sound by using "run a program" in association with various events.  In that case, you can have it run one of the media players and specify a sound file (which can include a system sound file).  Specific instructions will depend on your exact configuration and the events you want to sound.